# Почему при записи данных из БД в массив они дублируются?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с проблемой записи в массив данных из mysql. При выводе массива объявленного в результате выборки из базы получаются вот такие вот дубли.

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("lightside_db");
    mysql_set_charset("utf8");

    if(!$connection || !$db){
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, image, date, author FROM news ORDER BY date");
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo $key." => ".$value."<br>";
    }
?>
```

[image: А вот сам код]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В фкнкции  mysql_fetch_array($result); добавь 2 параметром, вот так
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC). Если не указывать флаг, то будет возвращать и числовой и ассоциативные ключи со значениеми.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: А вообще стоит использовать PDO, mysql и mysqli морально устарели)

Comment: Не слышал ещё даже о таком :с

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php Просто зайдите на страницу